# Capistrano Deploy SSH Connection Timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I am collaborating with another developer on an app. It is a ruby on rails app using capistrano to deploy to an amazon AWS EC2 instance. I am developing on a local machine and am able to run the command `bundle exec production deploy`. This works properly and updates the code base and deploys properly.
My partner developer is using gitpod to develop and needs to be able to deploy as well. I have attempted to deploy from gitpod but am experiencing issues.

I am using Capistrano 3.17.3, sshkit 1.21.5, ruby 2.7.3, and rails 6.0.6

I believe configuration is largely completed, the master.key is copied over from my local machine, the linked dir and such are all identical to when I deploy on my local machine. However, when I attempt to deploy from my collaborators gitpod, I encounter the following error:

```
Caused by:
Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) for 3.218.XXX.XXX:22
/home/gitpod/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/socket.rb:64:in `connect'
/home/gitpod/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/socket.rb:64:in `connect_internal'
/home/gitpod/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/socket.rb:137:in `connect'
/home/gitpod/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/socket.rb:642:in `block in tcp'
/home/gitpod/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/socket.rb:227:in `each'
/home/gitpod/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/socket.rb:227:in `foreach'
/home/gitpod/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/socket.rb:632:in `tcp'
/workspace/tourme_mvp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:72:in `initialize'
/workspace/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:256:in `new'
/workspace/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:256:in `start'
/workspace/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.5/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `call'
/workspace/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.5/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `with'
/workspace/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.5/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:177:in `with_ssh'
/workspace/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.5/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:130:in `execute_command'
/workspace/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
/workspace/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `tap'
/workspace/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
/workspace/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:61:in `test'
/workspace/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/capistrano-rbenv-2.2.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/rbenv.rake:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/workspace/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
/workspace/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
/workspace/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.5/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => rbenv:validate
```

It is notable that the server and my local machine are configured to use Rbenv while the gitpod is using rvm. I don't think this is the primary issue because the issue is the ssh connection.

The following is my config/deploy.rb:

```
require 'capistrano-db-tasks'

set :application, 'app_name'
set :repo_url, 'repo_url'

set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/app_name'
set :branch, ENV['BRANCH'] if ENV['BRANCH']


set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/master.key}
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

set :keep_releases, 3
set :keep_assets, 3

set :db_local_clean, true
set :db_remote_clean, true

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

And the following is my config/deploy/production.rb:

```
server '3.218.XXX.XXX', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db}
server '34.238.XXX.XXX', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db}
set :rails_env, 'production'
```

where the server ip addresses are the AWS EC2 public ips. There are two instances

I followed this youtube video to initially set up my ec2 instances:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJzYmhxB8rE

Again, the linked files are configured properly. Is there something I am missing? Is capistrano deployment from gitpod unreasonable? Is there some method capistrano is using to SSH that I am missing? Although there may be other errors, it appears that none of them can yet be encountered because Capistrano can't SSH into the EC2 instances.

Comment: Likely gitpod doesn't have the proper SSH credentials set up

Comment: @dbugger Could you clarify what you mean by that? I understand gitpod has options to ssh into the gitpod itself but how does one set up ssh within gitpod to something else?